# Let $V$ a $K$ - vector space. Proof that $W$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a $K$- vector space and $W \subseteq V$. Proof that $W$ is a subspace of $V \Longleftrightarrow W$ is nonempty and $\lambda u + v$  $\in W,\space \forall \lambda \in K, \space \forall u,v \in W$.

I already proved that $W$ is a subspace of $V \Longrightarrow W$ is nonempty and $\lambda u + v$  $\in W...$ and just need some help for the other part of the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u \in W$. Then $(-1)u+u \in W$ so $0 \in W$. Taking $\lambda =1$ in the hypothesis we see that $u+v \in W$ whenever $u,v \in W$. Taking $v=0$ in the hypothesis we see that $\lambda u \in W$ for all $\lambda \in K$ and $u \in W$. Hence $W$ is  subspace.